# How to create a global variable in Shopify?

Tags: global-variables, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I'm trying to create a Shopify's dynamic global variable from one of my custom pages AND that has to be usable in a notification email template such as {{ customer.first_name }}.

So when a client visits the page, it should automatically creates or changes the variable's value depending on the client.

I have seen these answers below from research so far,

1. Assigning value by using liquid's assign .

eg)

```
{% assign global_variable %}
```

problem) This only works on the same page.

2. Setting the variable on settings_schema.json file.

eg)

```
{
"type": "text",
"id": "global_variable",
"label": "global variable",
"default": "Variable value"
}
```

prob) This works globally in all liquid files, but not in the Shopify's notification email templates.

3. using metafield.

eg)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/api/2020-04/metafields.json',
    namespace: "inventory",
    key: "testing",
    value: "testingtesitng",
    value_type: "string",
    success: function(data) { 
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      Shopify.onError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus);
    }
});
```

prob) I don't know if that's a correct POST call, but somehow I get a HTML code as response and it does not work either on any liquid file or email template.

Long story short, I just want to know if it's possible to create a variable that can be used in notification email templates like customer.first_name or shop.global_variable etc.

I would really appreciate if any help !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify theme and email template/notifications are different platforms, they don't share variables.

You can think it like a website and a mailchimp, they don't share the same code, so you can't access for example a JS variable from a site inside the MailChimp template.

The same logic applies here, Shopify email templates are scoped for themselves, they don't share variables between themselves or between the site.

---

So long story short, no you can't create a global variable in the Shopify theme and pass it to the notification email.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, if you are correct, I'm wondering how they assign variables with customers' names once they purchase a product. What I mean is, when a customer visits my website and purchase a product, they fill in their personal information, then Shopify automatically set their name in a variable so I can use in the templates like this {{ customer.first_name }}. It means at the time a customer purchases a product, from some place Shopify stores the information the user fill in. I think there must be a way ? not sure though..

Comment: @JayJeong those objects are available inside the email template, they are not pulled from the theme. You are mismatching the logic here. You can see the full list of variables here https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/notifications/email-variables When you make an order the customer is saved in the database, the notification templates pulls the customer from there, not from the theme. You can have a shopify store without a theme and the notification template will still have access to the customer data. Please read on Shopify liquid and notification template.

Comment: I see.. some articles say I can send POST request to their server using metafield and use it as {{ shop.global_variable }}. Is this also not possible for template use? ref: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/NEED-TO-CREATE-A-GLOBAL-VARIABLE/td-p/130448  If it's really not possible I should look for another way..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use metafields. After creating a metafield, you can retrieve it on the template liquid file easily.

After you create the metafield, you can try if it is stored with the metafield get request. Just post the link on browser to see if it's correct.

If it's correct, you can load it on the liquid file. Personally, I use metafield to save custom meta tags and load it to liquid. It works very well

Answer (score 0):

Let me highlight some key points:

**Theme Customization:**

- Using theme customization we can not set a global variable which may be accessible in the Shopify Email template(s).

**Custom APP:**

- If you are familiar with Shopify APP development then we can do a trick.

1. Shopify give us "shop.metafields". You can add data in "shop.metafields" using the end point "/admin/metafields.json" [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield)
2. After adding the data you can access the metafields in the email template by using following simple liquid syntax

   `{{ shop.metafields }}`

**FYI** - I did that before for myself

**Note: You can not call the API without APP or using AJAX call at theme level**

All the best